# Displaying a close image on hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover

```
<body>
<div id="content" >
    <img id="Image1" src = "img.png" />

</div>
</body>
```

I want to display a close image on top right when hovered over another image(Image1).
How can this be done in css also i'm using jquery.

Comment: i mean a custom cancel image...

Comment: $('img').hover(function(){$(this).prepend('<img class="close" src="close.png"/>')}).blur(function(){$('.close').remove()});

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create the close image. You then need to style `#content` div and add the hover to `#content` as follows:

```
<div id="content" >
    <img id="Image1" src = "img.png" />
    <img id="close" src="/path/to/close/image/close.png" />
</div>

#content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}

.close{
    position:absolute;
    right:-10px; top:-10px; /* Will place the close image in the top right edge of the image */
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}

#content:hover .close{
    display:block;
}
```

Using JQuery, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.close').show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('.close').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

give the close image a z-index higher than the image you're hovering over and position the close image absolute then place it in the correct position with an opacity of 0 then use jquery to animate the opacity on hover

Comment: @user1184100 here it is in action: (updated) http://jsfiddle.net/RxvLn/1/ you can substitute the div im using for the x with an image

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS, however it would most likely not work in IE7 or lower

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <img id="Image1" src="img.png" />
        <img class="close" src="close.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS Method:

```
#content { position: relative; }
#content .close { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#content:hover .close { display: block; }
```

---

**UPDATED**

To show a fade in/out effect for the close button, you'll need to use jQuery:

```
$("#content").hover(function() {
    $(".close", $(this)).stop(true).fadeIn();
},
function() {
    $(".close", $(this)).stop(true).fadeOut();
]);
```

Comment: @user1184100 true, but if you want the fading effect you'll have to use jquery.

Comment: I thought Image1 was the image that needed a close image over it :/

Comment: he wants ANOTHER image floating above this image, otherwise this solution would definitively be the best :)

Comment: Yep, edited. @codewombat I'm not sure where you've got the need for a fading effect from as it's not mentioned in the OP, but you're right that jQuery would be the only solution in that case.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan well he stated that he's using jquery, so naturally i assumed it was for effects. so if he's gonna use jquery anyway why not spiff it up and make it look nice :)

Comment: @user1184100 I've updated my answer to show you the fade in/out code.

Comment: How can i do it for multiple images within a same div .. for example    <div id="content" >
  <img id="safariImg" src = "images/safari.png" />
  <img id="bird_twitter" src = "images/bird_twitter.png" />
  <img id="cancelImg" class = "cancel" src = "cancel_round_12.png" />
</div>                                                              Now i have multiple images within same div so in css if i have styling as #content img:hover .cancel{ display:block; } it doesnt seem to work..

Answer (score 1):

first make a mockup showing your close image in the top right. When you've managed this, use jquery to show it on hover:

```
$('#Image1').on('mouseenter', function() { $('#closeImg').show(); });
```

placing the close image can be done something like this:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="close-img"><img src="..." /></div>
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

css:

```
.img-container { position: relative; }
.close-img { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 99; }
```

--- edit: use the jquery example above if you want some effects, otherwise use the pure css solution (`.img-container:hover .close-img { display: block }`) as given by others